# Upload non-latin name file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have simple form to ajax-upload files to server.

Here is input event listener:

```
$(document).on('change', '.js-file', function(event){

    sendFile(event);
});
```

And here is the function that actually uploads the file:

```
function sendFile (event) {
    var files = event.target.files;


    var action = '/ajax-upload-files/';
    var data = new FormData();

    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        data.append(key, value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){

        },
        complete: function(data) {
        }
    });
}
```

It wors fine with all kinds of files, except those with non-latin characters in the file name, e.g. Максим.jpg

The data is being sent to server, as I see in Chrome network. But when I try to dump $_FILES on server, it seems to be empty.

```
var_dump($_FILES) //array(0) {}
```

I don't really understand what's wrong - contentLength of the request header is much smaller then it should be - it looks like file was not appended to form for some reason.

Comment: your code looks find and should work fine(as i had tried it with no errors). but first of all, you have a syntax error in your ajax code where you have `xhr: function() {` you have not defined your function and not closed it. I checked your code with out this line and it worked perfect with files with `utf-8` names.

Comment: I just have deleted xhr block to shorten example...

Comment: i ve managed to upload file, but I hade to read it in FileReader and upoad as binary - FormData does not accept cyrillyc names. Have no idea why.

Comment: I think I still have not understand your problem. you mentioned that `var_dump($_FILES)` returns `array(0)` but as i tried just echoing back `var_dump($_FILES)` from my `php` file to my `ajax` and write the result in console, I see that I I have one file object in it with correct name and size. now can you explain if you have reached to this point and have problem after this point(which I think will be related to your php code) or not?

Comment: no, its not related to php - image is not appended to form for some reason. same code with english name file works, with Максим1.jpg does not

Could not figure out what is the problem. Had to use binary to send it.

Comment: I you know any upload-freandly anonymous servers, I'll make feedle to illustrate problem

Comment: Your code works just fine on my wamp server on windows 7. I'll just post and answer with your code which I use and the server response so we can discuss more under it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to upload non-latin name file.
Have to read it as binary and send as binary.

HTML:

```
<input class="js-file" name="filename" type="file">
```

And js

```
//Handler in input
$(document).on('change', '.js-file', function(event){
            var file_name = $(this).attr('name');


            var reader = new FileReader();
            var f = event.target.files[0],
                nameArr = event.target.files[0]['name'].split('.'),
                extension = nameArr[nameArr.length-1]; //here we can check if extension is allowed

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var contents = e.target.result;
                contents = contents.split('base64,')[1]; //we need only encoded part

                sendFileAsBinary(file_name, extension, contents);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);


        });
```

And sender:

```
function sendFileAsBinary(file_name, extension, img) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax-upload-files/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            name: file_name,
            img: img,
            extension: extension
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){


        },
        complete: function(data) {

        }

    })

}
```

And php code to decode image:

```
 $name = $this->_getParam('name');
 $extension = $this->_getParam('extension');
 $computedName = $name . '.' . $extension;

 $fileContent = base64_decode($this->_getParam('img'));

 file_put_contents($fileContent, $computedName);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code I'm using(your code):

**HTML file**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('change', '#fileToUpload', function(event){
    sendFile(event);
});

function sendFile (event) {
    var files = event.target.files;
    var myAction = 'test.php';
    var myData = new FormData();

    $.each(files, function(key, value){
        myData.append(key, value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: myAction,
        type: 'POST',
        data: myData,
        cache: false,
//        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function(data) {
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
echo var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

**result in console.log()**

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=5)</i>
      'name' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Максим.jpg'</font> <i>(length=16)</i>
      'type' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'image/jpeg'</font> <i>(length=10)</i>
      'tmp_name' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'C:\wamp\tmp\phpE01A.tmp'</font> <i>(length=23)</i>
      'error' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>0</font>
      'size' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>951214</font>
</pre>
```

so, as you can see, my code uploads file and server can see it. do you have different results on your machine?

Comment: I've posted code that works. Previous version doen't work. There no $_FILES on server at all. It's empty array. I don't know why - all other files are sent correctly. Only exception - is this file, that differs as I see, only in russian flename.